# How to replace multi-digit number in file using sed?

Tags: shell, sed

I'd like to replace an number in file which is multi-digit (from 1 digit up to 3).

***server.properties***

```
###
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
enable-command-block=false
max-players=61
##max-players can be 0 up to 100##
network-compression-threshold=256
resource-pack-sha1=
###
```

***Tried so far***

```
sed -i -e 's/max-players=[^0-9]/max-players=40/g' /home/TIXB9HQFV0/server.properties
```

but is doesn't work. I know that it is possible to replace e.g. `10` using

```
sed -i -e 's/max-players=[0-9][0-9]/max-players=40/g' /home/TIXB9HQFV0/server.properties
```

The point is that the amount of digits is different.
Any ideas to get this working?

***Expected output***

```
###
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
enable-command-block=false
max-players=40
network-compression-threshold=256
resource-pack-sha1=
###
```

Comment: Please show us sample Input and sample expected output so that we could help you here.

Comment: Updated my question. An example and expected result is now shown,

Comment: replace [0-9][0-9] with[0-9]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `sed` could help you on same then:

```
sed -E 's/max-players=[0-9]+/max-players=40/g'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
###
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
enable-command-block=false
max-players=40
##max-players can be 0 up to 100##
network-compression-threshold=256
resource-pack-sha1=
###
```

As per OP if you need to make changes in Input_file itself then use `sed -i` command in above given one.

Comment: It shows me the result in the command output, but does not replace it in file.

Comment: @M.Miles, use `sed -i` command if you want output into the Input_file itself.